# .net 6 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - after object instantiation, data is valid

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

Now, before someone shoots me - I know this has been asked A LOT here.  I've read through and still can't understand quite what's going on.  I have a Windows Forms application, using .net 6.  I have created two models, which will contain a list of payment details, then the second model will contain a list of the payment details, along with two other items.

I wrote this around a year ago, when I was learning C# and have returned to it understanding a little better (now using models, whereas I didn't have them previously).  There may be an error in the Populate function which causes the error, which I'm not aware of.  Feedback of code always appreciated.

The Populate function takes in a List of strings, which are comma separated.  There is an array of integers passed in, which will denoted where in the comma delimted object, the correct location of the value required, which is then assigned to it's respective variable.

The two models are:

```
public class PaymentData
{
    public string SortCode { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string PayeeName { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string PayeeReference { get; set; }
}
public class PaymentList
{
    public List<PaymentData> PaymentData { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; } = new Decimal(0);
    public int NumberOfRows { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

And my code where these are instantiated:

```
public static PaymentList Populate(List<string> ArrayData, int[] DataPosition)
    {
        // Create a new PaymentList object
        PaymentList paymentList = new PaymentList();  

        // Let's check if any of the DataPosition elements return -1 (is not set)
        if (DataPosition[0] != -1 &&
            DataPosition[1] != -1 &&
            DataPosition[2] != -1 &&
            DataPosition[3] != -1)
        {
            // Loop through each line within ArrayData
            foreach (string lineArr in ArrayData)
            {
                if (lineArr.Length > 4)
                {
                    string[] line = lineArr.Split(",");                        

                    // Get the Sort Code from the array
                    string SortCodeString = StringReplace.clean(line[DataPosition[0]].ToString().Trim());

                    if (SortCodeString.Contains("/"))
                    {
                        (string SortCode, bool Status) = SortCodeCheckIsDate.DateCheck(SortCodeString);
                        if (Status)
                        {
                            SortCodeString = SortCode;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DisplayMessage.MessageShow("Sort Code", SortCodeString);
                        }
                    }

                    // Check that the Sort Code is 6 digits, and only numeric
                    bool CheckSortCodeIsInt = int.TryParse(SortCodeString, out int SortCodeOut);
                    if (SortCodeString.Length != 6 | !CheckSortCodeIsInt)
                    {
                        DisplayMessage.MessageShow("Sort Code", SortCodeString);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Check that the Account Number is 8 digits, and only numeric
                    string AccountNoString = line[DataPosition[1]].ToString().PadLeft(8, '0').Trim();

                    bool CheckAccountNoIsInt = int.TryParse(AccountNoString, out int AccountNoOut);

                    if (AccountNoString.Length != 8 | !CheckAccountNoIsInt)
                    {
                        DisplayMessage.MessageShow("Account Number", AccountNoString);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Check Employee Name string length greater than zero
                    string EmployeeNameString = line[DataPosition[2]].ToString().Trim();
                    if (EmployeeNameString.Length == 0)
                    {
                        DisplayMessage.MessageShow("Employee Name", null);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Check that the Amount is a decimal place value
                    string AmountString = line[DataPosition[3]].ToString();
                    bool CheckAmountIsDecimal = decimal.TryParse(AmountString, out decimal AmountOut);
                    if (CheckAmountIsDecimal || AmountString.Contains("."))
                    {
                        // Sum the total Amount to display in the UI
                        paymentList.Amount += decimal.Parse(AmountString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DisplayMessage.MessageShow("Amount", AmountString);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Set PayRefString from the input box paymentRef                        
                    string PayRefString = DataPosition[4] > -1 ? line[DataPosition[4]].ToString().Trim() : "None";

                    // Create a new row for DataTable and add data
                    PaymentData payment = new PaymentData
                    {                      
                        SortCode = SortCodeString.Trim(),
                        AccountNumber = AccountNoString.Trim(),
                        PayeeName = EmployeeNameString.Trim(),
                        Amount = AmountOut,
                        PayeeReference = PayRefString
                    };

                    // Create a new ListViewItem, assigned from the row variable
                    paymentList.PaymentData.Add(payment);

                    // Increment the NumRow variable by 1
                    paymentList.NumberOfRows++;
                }
            }                
        }
        return paymentList;
    }
```

The error occurs at:

```
PaymentData payment = new PaymentData    
{                      
    SortCode = SortCodeString,
    AccountNumber = AccountNoString,
    PayeeName = EmployeeNameString,
    Amount = AmountOut,
    PayeeReference = PayRefString
};
```

I have validated that `SortCodeString`, `AccountNoString`, `EmployeeNameString`, `AmountOut` (int) and `PayRefString` are all valid.

Once PaymentData has been populated, it's added into the List under PaymentList

I just don't understand why, when I'm trying to insert into a new instantiation of `PaymentData`, it's giving me the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Correct property declaration with initilization `public List<PaymentData> PaymentData { get; set; } = new List<PaymentData>();`

Comment: That's the solution to the issue - wasn't aware of the declaration being made in this way.  Thank you @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets - I suspect that a lot of the code you've provided *isn't* required for us to reproduce this, but we can't reproduce it with *just* this code. I'd also strongly advise you to learn about and start following .NET naming conventions - in particular, using `pascalCase` for local variables.

Comment: If that's the solution, then your claim about "The error occurs at:" was incorrect - it was at `paymentList.PaymentData.Add(payment)`, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet when the error displays in VS, it highlights that portion of code.  But it does appear to fail on the line after that, when trying to insert into List<PaymentData>

Comment: I don't know which version of the compiler do you use, but other solution is to assign list  right after `paymentList` creation: `paymentList.PaymentData = new List<PaymentData>();`

Comment: This is where stepping through the code to check where it's *actually* failing would have been a good move before creating the question. (Along with creating a [mcve].)

Comment: @JonSkeet I did step through the code, but this is where the confusion was, it was highlighting the the creation of the PaymentData, not the PaymentList.  It only ever stopped at that block, never on the `paymentList.PaymentData.Add(payment);` However, I do appreciate that it should be have been a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: That suggests you weren't actually stepping through the latest code. The code that you're saying failed *really* shouldn't have failed. You might want to get back to the broken version just to check your debug setup. (Better to spend time on that now when you know where it's really broken than waste time later not being able to debug reliably.)

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for the feedback, I still have a way to learn with C#, but making slow steady progress.  Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SvyatoslavDanyliv has provided the correct initialization of the model with the List of PaymentData.  Revised model is now:

```
public class PaymentList
    {
        public List<PaymentData> PaymentData { get; set; } = new List<PaymentData>();
        public Decimal Amount { get; set; } = new Decimal(0);
        public int NumberOfRows { get; set; } = 0;
    }
```